# Problem in showing that a norm is a norm on one space, but not on another.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have the following question from a past paper:

"*Consider the two sets,*

$$A=\{g\in C^1([0,1]):g(0)=g(1)=0\}$$

*and,*

$$B=\{g\in C^1([0,1]):g'(0)=g'(1)=0\}$$

*both subsets of the vector space $C^1([0,1])$, and define for both $A,B$, that,*

$$\|g\|_1=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|g'(x)|$$

*$(a)$ Show that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is a norm on $A$ but not a norm on $B.$*

*$(b)$ Show that $A\cap B$ is a linear subspace of $C^1([0,1])$, and give an example of some $g\in A\cap B$, $g\neq0$"*

For part (a) I started by going through the four properties that define a norm, namely that, for all $x,y$ in a normed vector space $X$, and for all $\alpha\in\mathbb F$, there is a function $\|\cdot\|$ such that,

$$ \|x\|\ge0$$

$$\|x\|=0\iff x=0$$

$$\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|$$

$$\|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|$$

Whilst I think that I have shown this for $\|\cdot\|_1$ on the first set, $A$, I am not sure how to go about showing this for the second set, $B$. Looking at the requirement defined in $B$ for $g$, that $g'(0)=g'(1)=0$, I thought that the only function that could be a member of $B$ would be the zero function, so that the first property of a norm fails to hold true. However, the fact that in part $(b)$ it says to give an example of some function in the intersection of $A$ and $B$ that is **not** the zero function leads me to think that I am wrong.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem, by using the properties of a norm, or is there another way? To that end, can anybody direct me how to better tackle showing that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is not a norm on $B$.

Comment: Formulation mishap: Instead of "for all $x,y$ in $X$ and for all $\alpha\in\mathbb F$ there is a function $\|\cdot\|$ such that" you mean "The given function $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ has the property that for all $x,y\in X$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb F$ ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) Consider $g(t)=1$.

(b) Consider $g(t)=t^2(1-t)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: choose any constant function $g$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Then $g \in B$ but $g$ is not the zero function.